# "...pictures from/by Sarah" - What is the difference?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> 1. It's one of my all time favourite pictures from Sarah;
> 2. It's one of my all time favourite pictures by Sarah.

Are they grammatically correct? What is the difference between them?

Comment: Angel, please visit [ell.se] if you have more questions. :)

Answer (score 2):

Except for a missing hyphen, both sentences are grammatically correct but mean completely different things.

> It's one of my all-time favourite pictures from Sarah

means that Sarah gives/sends you pictures and this picture is one of your favourites from her. This sentence doesn't specify the origin of the pictures.

> It's one of my all-time favourite pictures by Sarah

means that Sarah takes pictures and this picture is one of your favourite pictures she has taken.